# How to convert string into datetime in Python

Tags: python, datetime, odoo-11

i have concatenated

```
date(date field)
time(float)
date_time_to(Char)
```

i am getting output in this format `"2018-10-09 20.00"`.

I need output in this format `'%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S'`

I used `"obj.date_time_to = datetime.strptime(self.date_time_to, "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S.%f")"`

i am getting

```
ValueError: time data '2018-10-09 20.00' does not match format '%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S.%f'
```

Comment: Your format string has to match the input value. Yours uses different dividers and is longer. The order of the date fields is also wrong.

Comment: Why exactly are you expecting just `%m/%d/%Y` to match `2018-10-09` ?

Comment: You might want to look at how datetime operates, it seems you do not understand how the formatting parameters work. `%m/%d%Y` would  be a date in month/day/Year. You need to adjust it to your input, as seen in @schwobaseggi's answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to parse the string with the right format:

```
from datetime import datetime

input = "2018-10-09 20.00"
#        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^-----⌄⌄⌄⌄⌄⌄⌄⌄⌄⌄⌄⌄⌄⌄
d = datetime.strptime(input, "%Y-%m-%d %H.%M")  # parse to datetime object
result = d.strftime("%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S")        # now convert to desired format
#⌄⌄⌄⌄⌄⌄⌄⌄⌄⌄⌄⌄⌄⌄⌄⌄⌄⌄⌄-^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ 
'10/09/2018 20:00:00'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `datetime` module. Check the [Python](https://docs.python.org) documentation.

For example:

```
import datetime

x = "09/10/2018"
date = datetime.datetime.strptime(date, "%d/%M/%Y") # string to datetime
```